# Delimiting the IO monad

Tags: haskell, io, monads

It's nice to know (in Safe Haskell, at least) from the signature whether or not something performs IO actions, but IO encompasses a lot of different things - `putStr`, database access, removing and writing to files, IORefs, etc.

If I'm using the type signatures as a security measure when running arbitrary code, it might be the case that I'm willing to accept some IO actions - `putStr` and the ilk, for instance - but not others.

Is there a way to define a restricted version of the IO monad, with only a subset of the normal IO actions? If so, an example (with `putStr`, for instance) would be very welcome!

Comment: Here's a [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1p6gth/io_with_permissions/) I made a while back about this exact problem.  There's a good discussion there and example code that you could use to base an implementation off of.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a follow up to my comment, you can implement it yourself with something like

```
class Monad io => Stdout io where
    putStr_ :: String -> io ()
    putStrLn_ :: String -> io ()
    print_ :: Show a => a -> io ()
    -- etc

instance Stdout IO where
    putStr_ = putStr
    putStrLn_ putStrLn
    print_ = print

myFunc :: Stdout io => io ()
myFunc = do
    val <- someAction
    print_ val
    let newVal = doSomething val
    print_ newVal

main :: IO ()
main = myFunc
```

This will have absolutely no runtime overhead, since GHC will optimize away those typeclasses to use only the `IO` monad, it's extensible, easy to write, and can be combined with monad transformes and the `MonadIO` class quite easily.  If you have multiple class, such as a `Stdin` class with `getLine_`, `getChar_`, etc defined, you can even combine these typeclasses with

```
class (Stdout io, Stdin io) => StdOutIn io where

myFunc :: StdOutIn io => io ()
myFunc = do
    val <- getLine_
    putStrLn_ $ "Echo: " ++ val

main :: IO ()
main = myFunc
```

Comment: +1 since this composes well. You can build small type classes for `Stdout`, file access, networks, missile-firing, whatever and then combine them arbitrarily and smoothly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after!

Comment: With -XConstraintKinds, you can write `type StdOutIn io = (Stdout io, Stdin io)` for similar effect.

Comment: @AlexR would there be a benefit to using constraint kinds as opposed to what I've shown here? I would think that it's the same effect for this case since the classes are so simple. It's an alternate syntax, but I don't think I'd gain any functional value with that extension. I could be wrong, though, I don't pretend to be an expert.

Comment: None that I can think of, at least directly. Check out the `constraints` package, though.

Answer (score 10):

Just define a `newtype` around `IO a` with a Monad instance, define wrapped versions of your pre-approved functions, and *don't export the constructor*, so that only the functions you wrapped can be used in the monad.