# Are there valid reasons to build monad transformer stacks on top of IO?

Tags: haskell, io, monads

`IO` is tricky in Haskell. Threads, FFI, async exceptions, laziness, you name it.

And then we have `MonadIO` which allows layering monadic stacks with `IO` at the bottom. Since `IO` actions can do arbitrary things, what is the value of building monadic stacks on top of such shaky foundations?

Why does it exist? Why not build a custom monad `IO` if you really need to perform arbitrary side effects?

Comment: But that's what we do...? [`MonadIO` is just a typeclass](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=MonadIO) which groups all such 'custom monads' together. It just so happens that a lot of useful monads can be expressed as monad transformer stacks. Are you sure you're clear about what you're asking here?

Comment: Suppose I give you my library that does some useful things but all are in `MonadIO`. Would you use it without worrying about library writing files, using network or forking threads? Would you use a newer version of it without inspecting source code what those `IO` actions actually do?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why it's being marked as a bad question.

Comment: What do you mean by "*but* are all in `MonadIO`"? Are you saying that we can't know what goes on in an `IO` action? Having monad transformers *helps* us understand that, not hinders. I'm still not clear on what your question is. I'd recommend making a concrete example.

Comment: @AJFarmar sevo seems to be asking why don't we use a fine-grained effect system of some sort everywhere. Cf. suggestions like [*Delimiting the IO monad*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20318936/2751851) and https://chrispenner.ca/posts/monadio-considered-harmful

Comment: @duplode thank you - these confirm my concerns about MonadIO even I don't have experience to state exactly how I see this as a problem. I think it boils down to consumer/producer of the API where consumer should not be forced to use MonadIO but provide an instance of some MonadEffect instead.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/fpco/unliftio/tree/master/unliftio#readme

Answer (score 1):

It's a common approach these days to use [the ReaderT design pattern](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern).

You are correct to be wary of putting other transformers on top of IO, and the above linked blog post explains some of those reasons.

However, ReaderT provides a nice little convenience when it comes to passing "common app config" around to all of your functions.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the value of building monadic stacks on top of such shaky
>   foundations?

Transformers on top of `IO` might let you talk more conveniently about sequences of repeated actions (hence the [various](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) [libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes)).

They might also help with the required bookkeeping of [externally allocated resources](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet).

The "wildness" of `IO` is not a general objection to stacking transformers on top of it, since they can help you to avoid repetitive code and make the essential logic clearer.

Rather, the [argument](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZIN9f9rI34) is that `IO` already provides some built-in functionality for handling errors ([exceptions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html)) and mutable references ([`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html)s, [`MVars`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html)...) so adding transformers for that already existing functionality might be overkill.

One argument for mutable references in particular is that state maintained by "pure" means vanishes when an exception pops up, and that might not be what you want. You can also access mutable references from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

`MonadIO` can be useful when implementing functions for a type that is *not* an instance of `MonadIO`.

```
newtype FooMonad a
  = FooMonad (StateT Int IO a)
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

doFoo :: FooMonad String
doFoo = FooMonad $ liftIO getLine
```

You can use the `MonadIO` instances of `StateT Int` and `IO` to define "primitive" `FooMonad` actions conveniently. Others using your module are limited to just the primitives you choose to export.